# adding useMemo or useCallbacks to the map component breaks the code with error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-google-maps

#### what im trying to do

- place a marker on the map and calculate the distance between the marker and a static location on the map.

#### problem description

- previously my useEffect was causing re renders ,now when i try to cache the functions i get this error.

```
   Unhandled Runtime Error
        Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render line 27
```

- line 27 is where i use useCallback .
- placing marker on the map causes effect to run and calculate the distance .
- All the options provided to GoogleMap component are outside the functional component .
- To avoid re-creating onMapClick function, i'm trying to use UseCallback which leads to this error . same error with useMemo too .
- Even if i comment out the onMapClick function and remove it from GoogleMap prop the re rendering issue persists.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
    import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';
    
    const libraries = ['places'];
    const mapContainerStyle = {
      width: '100%',
      height: '40vh',
    };
    const center = {
      lat: 25.33800452203996,
      lng: 55.393221974372864,
    };
    const options = {
      zoomControl: true,
    };
    
    const initialMarker = { lat: null, long: null };
    export default function index() {
      const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
        googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
        libraries,
      });
      const [marker, setMarker] = useState(initialMarker);
      if (loadError) return 'Error Loading Maps';
      if (!isLoaded) return 'Loading Maps';
    
      const onMapClick = useCallback((event) => {
        setMarker({
          lat: event.latLng.lat(),
          lng: event.latLng.lng(),
        });
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (
          google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
            new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat, center.lng),
            new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng)
          ) > 1000
        ) {
          console.log('out of bounds');
        }
      }, [marker.lat]);
      return (
        <div>
          <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
            zoom={14}
            options={options}
            center={center}
            onClick={onMapClick}></GoogleMap>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

#### reference from similar re-rendering issue

- i tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64744730/13949571) too , didnt help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
  if (loadError) return 'Error Loading Maps';
  if (!isLoaded) return 'Loading Maps';

  const onMapClick = useCallback((event) => {
    setMarker({
      lat: event.latLng.lat(),
      lng: event.latLng.lng(),
    });
  }, []);
```

The `if` conditions above may cancel calling some hooks, **hence the warning**. You shouldn't use hooks [conditionally](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). You need to refactor your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply ! i get "google is not defined" error now . I'll update after figuring this out.

Comment: @MohamedSauood you should normally accept or upvote if answer helped you; and if there is other issue you can ask new question.

Comment: Sorry My Bad ! Much Thanks